# How can I use LINQ to filter a collection of nested classes to yield a dictionary of unique properties of those classes?

Tags: vb.net, linq, class, dictionary, nested

I have two classes, one nested in the other.

```
Public Class Operation

    Public Property Name
    Public Property Records As List(Of Record)

    Public Class Record

        Public Property ID as Integer
```

Now, I have a collection of operations -->

```
Dim pOperations as List(Of Operation)
```

Neither "Name" or "ID" are unique between operations and records.

I wish to construct a dictionary using LINQ = Dictionary(Of String, Of List(Of Integer), whereby the keys are uniqe examples of Names in my collection and the values are the collective set of distinct IDs that are associated with those names.

Comment: I don't really recall the best way to do this in VB's syntax. But it would be select many from operations to record.id combined into a `Name` + `Record`.`id` object. Then group by `Name`, and map the group by object into a dictionary.

Comment: Thanks for answering - that's one step. However, I'm in the position of struggling with the syntax. If anyone out there can add to Travis's thoughts, that would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tim Scmelter's suggested code pretty much did the trick.  I had to make one small change to make my record IDs unique and it was good-to-go.

```
Dim dict = (From op In pOperations _
            From rec In op.Records _
            Group rec By op.Name Into NameGrp = Group) _
           .ToDictionary(Function(grp) (grp.Name), _
                         Function(grp) (grp.NameGrp.Select(Function(r) _ 
                                                           (r.ID)).Distinct().ToList))
```

Answer (score 2):

This creates a `Dictionary(Of String, List(Of Int32))` with the unique names as key and it's associated Record-ID's as values.

```
Dim dict = (From op In pOperations
            From rec In op.Records
            Group rec By op.Name Into NameGrp = Group) _
           .ToDictionary(Function(grp) (grp.Name),
                         Function(grp) (grp.NameGrp.Select(Function(r) (r.ID)).ToList))
```

Comment: Thanks Tim :) - your response was really helpful and instructive.